# Delete using checkbox in codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, checkbox

I am having trouble regarding my checkbox delete in codeigniter. I have a form in which a table is displayed and populated with data from the database and there are two submit buttons. The first is the adduser button which I already did.

My problem is that I don't have any idea how to get the value of the checkbox in the displayed table. Here’s the snippet to understand more my problem:

Controller:

```
public function options()
    {
        $data['meta_title']="Users";
        $data['meta_desc']="Find your friends from our members";

        if ($this->input->post('AddUser'))
        {
            $this->load->view('template/header',$data);
            $this->load->view('users/add_view');
            $this->load->view('template/footer');
        }
        elseif($this->input->post('Delete'))
        {
            /// i have troubles with my logic here
        }
    }
```

View:

```
<?php foreach($query->result_array() as $row): ?>
        <tr class="even gradeC">
            <td><?php echo anchor('users/edit/'.$row['usrID'],$row['usrName']);?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['usrpFirstName'].' '.$row['usrpLastName'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['usrpBday'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['usrpSex'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['usrpAddress'];?></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkID[]" id="checkID" value="<?php echo $row['usrID'];?>" />

              <label for="checkID"></label></td>
        </tr>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would have been easier to understand your question if you'd actually add the submit button as well.

I'll try to explain you the principles;
You need to have a form to wrap the data you want to send, so for example:

```
<form action="whereToSendTheData.php" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr class="even gradeC">
            <td><?php echo anchor('users/edit/'.$row['usrID'],$row['usrName']);?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['usrpFirstName'].' '.$row['usrpLastName'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['usrpBday'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['usrpSex'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['usrpAddress'];?></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkID" id="checkID" value="<?php echo $row['usrID'];?>" />

            <label for="checkID"></label></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Add user">
</form>
```

this script will send the data within your form to the page "whereToSendTheData.php", which i defined in the "action" attribute above.

on "whereToSendData.php"
you need to have a script to process/fetch this data.
for example:

```
<?php
echo "hello $_POST['checkID']";
?>
```

which will output "hello" and the value of checkID.

you can read more about the subject, here:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp

Comment: yes i have the form.. thats why i just called it code snippet because it is not the whole code

Comment: ok, but does it answer your question? or do you still have a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You would better to use

```
<form method="post/get" action="url to ur controller">
   //some code to move data to controller
   <submit button>
</form>
```

and in your controller put a function to delete:

```
public function delete()
{
   //get the id's of rows which are checked and delete them as
   $this->db->where('userid in','array(checked ids)');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did everything great, setting input name as array was the correct choice.

Now, to  get the values of selected check box you can do like :

> $selectedUsers = $this->input->get('checkID') //If you have set the method of form as **GET**

or

> $selectedUsers =  $this->input->post('checkID') //If you have set the method of form as **POST**

Then in your model if you have the function

```
/**
 * @param array $values
 * @param string $field
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function remove_in($values, $field)
{
    if ($values === false) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $this->db->where_in($field, $values);

    return $this->db->delete($this->table);
}
```

You can call it from your controller like:

> $this->user_model->remove_in($selectedUsers, 'user_id');

Assuming your model name is **user_model** which you have loaded using `$this->load->model('user_model')` and the name of your user id field is **user_id**

Enjoy!

---

**NB:** Though it is nothing to do with your situation, But you should not use same id for multiple HTML element. Instead you could omit the id part if its not necessary like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkID[]" value="<?php echo $row['usrID'];?>" />
```

or if you need an ID you should use like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkID[]" id="checkID_<?php echo $row['usrID'];?>" value="<?php echo $row['usrID'];?>" />
```